# Selecting more than 1 object in a generic list

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine we have a car class with have some properties and one of them is engine displacement.

And i add all of the cars to a generic list.How can i select more than 1 object using a criteria using linq?

Tried using select many but couldnt get it running:

```
var fastcars = mycars.SelectMany(car => car.Engine >= 2000);
```

ps:normally i can select one object; for ex:

```
var selectedcar = mycars.First(car => car.Make == "Mercedes");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple `Where` clause .

```
var selectedcars = mycars.Where(car => car.Make == "Mercedes");
```

If you want to take multiple number of cars then you can use `Take`

```
var selectedcars = mycars.Where(car => car.Make == "Mercedes").Take(2);
```

You can add `ToList` or `ToArray` to get a list or array of objects respectively. Something like

```
var selectedcarsList = mycars.Where(car => car.Make == "Mercedes").Take(2).ToList();
```

Comment: +1, but maybe you could add `.ToList()`so he gets an actual list.

Comment: Well, OP doesn't say he _wants_ a list, only that he's selecting _from_ a list...

Answer (score 2):

EDITED (misread originally):

Try:

```
var cars = mycars.Where(car => car.Make == "Mercedes");
```

You may find [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) useful to help you learn a bit more about LINQ.

Comment: I think = should be == maybe thats why the downvote? (wasnt me)